# How to include javascript code into php view?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, yii2

I have to print news.php code out registering it into a variabile to put inside a grid in another view. My main problem is that the code in news.php doesn't show anything, after compilation it is just blank though I'm quite sure the script is working.

I've already tried to convert news.php into news.js but nothing changed, I guess there are problems in the registerJs().

news.php

```
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" 

src="http://islab.di.unimi.it/content/islab_site/media/com_islabteachpages/js/jquerynews.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://islab.di.unimi.it/content/islab_site/media/com_islabteachpages/js/jquery.jfeed.pack.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(function() {
        jQuery.getFeed({
            url: 'http://islab.di.unimi.it/iNewsMail/feed.php?channel=bdlab1',
            success: function(feed) {
                var html = '';
                for(var i = 0; i < feed.items.length && i < 10; i++) {

                    var item = feed.items[i];
                    html += '<div class="body-news">'
                        + '<b>'
                        + item.title
                        + '</b><br />'
                        + '<div>'
                        + item.description
                        + '</div>'
                        + ' </div>';
                }
                jQuery('#newsresult').append(html);
            }
        });
    });
</script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="newsresult">

</div>
</body>
```

view.php

```
     # put the js script inside my $news variable
     $this->registerJsFile(
         '@web/views/news.php',
         View::POS_HEAD);
     );
     echo '<div class="uk-grid">
            <div class="uk-width-2-3">
                <div class="itp_middle uk-width-1-1 uk-width-medium-3-5">
                    <div class="itp_section-1 ">
                        <div class="text">'
                            . $rows['content'] . '
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="uk-width-1-3">
                <div class="text">'
                    . $news . '
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>';
```

I expect the js code to be displayed inside the grid. Every help would be much appreciated.

Comment: You are not including jquery before your script...

Comment: what html is produced by your script? is the html from news.php included somewhere?

Comment: "TiagoCoelho" adding <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script> doesn't change anything. "wodka" no html is produced, just blank page and news.php must be included in view.php but idk the right way to do it.

Comment: if there is just a blank page then enable error reporting or take a look at the error log

Comment: Are you sure you're using Yii? How does your controller looks like?

Comment: In the controller I just render to the associate view.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't load jQuery in your page how can you execute the javascript code related to jQuery. It will directly throw error. This kind of error you can easily solve just by opening the browser's console.

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: jQuery.getFeed is not a function
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (news:60)
    at Object.resolveWith (jquerynews.js:2)
    at Function.ready (jquerynews.js:2)
    at HTMLDocument.C (jquerynews.js:2)                                                                        How can I load jQuery?